# Android studio anychart circular gauge

Tags: charts, circular-dependency, gauge, anychart

Can I set new data to AnyChartView??

when I use AnyChartView.setData(circularGauge); it creates itself below of my first chart.

this my setChart code.

```
        any_chart.setChart(circularGauge);
```

and one I need a full documentation for anychart circular gauge.

thank you all for answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to recreate or reapply the chart to update the data. All you need is to make chart active and apply new data to the existing chart. Here is the required code to apply new value 50:

```
APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(circularGauge);
circularGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new Integer[] {50}));
```

Here is the [Circular Gauges documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Gauges/Circular_Gauge). It's for the web version of the library, but the API is absolutely the same.

Comment: Thakn you very much.